# onload event triggered even the node is removed from dom

Tags: javascript, dom, event-listener, onload

```
<img id="img" src="src/abc.jpg" onload="imgload()"/>
<script>
   var img = document.getElementById("img");
   img.remove()
   function imgload(){
      console.log("image loaded now")
   }
</script>
```

Event though we removed the image from dom. the eventlistener was triggered. I know its a expected behaviour, but it seems like bug. please clarify.

Comment: "I know its a expected behaviour, but it seems like bug. please clarify." What makes you "feel" it's a bug, moreover since you "know" it's the expected behavior?

Comment: i am expecting a reason for this behaviour

Comment: What would be another behavior? And what would be your reasons for expecting that other behavior? To be clearer, are you expecting the event to not fire at all? For the listener to somehow be deactivated when the element isn't attached anymore? For the network request to be canceled? And then, should an error event fire? Or are you expecting yet something else?

Comment: The DOM isn't what events are applied to. Instead, elements receive events. Whether or not those elements are in the DOM isn't relevant in most cases.

Answer (score -1):

This might not be an correct explanation for your question, but i try to expain it from my POV.

While performing some searches, it came to know that onload function on image is an asynchronous function as it is related to fetch request.

you can also refer this link

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/460672/pexels-photo-460672.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" id="img" alt="" srcset="" onload="imgload()" />
  </div>
  <script>
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    img.remove();
    console.log('image removed');

    function imgload() {
      console.log(document);
      // run in the local system to see the document
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

while you run this code you will get output as
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhI5l.png)

you will know that the img is being removed from the DOM.
Thus this is asynchronous and does not depend on the image tag it depends on the image request.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).